# Chrome bluetooth api connect does not resolve

Tags: web-bluetooth

I am trying to follow the following example with no luck.
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/automatic-reconnect.html

The promise that is returned by the connect function never resolves. The example appears to imply that if a connection can't be made it should throw an error but this does not occur.

Comment: Is this on the first `connect()`, or only on subsequent calls to `connect()`?

Comment: this is on subsequent calls. i've also noticed that once a device disconnects for over a minute, i cannot even make a call to `requestDevice`. it just returns a pending promise that never resolves.

i've also tried to explicitly disconnect before connecting and that did not work either.

Comment: @ConleyOwens see above

Comment: i believe i am encountering this bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=684073. but on mac this promise never resolves even if the device comes back after a minute

Comment: What platforms are you using? This seems to be a bug. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs It may be a known one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=component%3ABlink%3EBluetooth%2CIO%3EBluetooth+summary%3Aconnect&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Stars+ReleaseBlock+Component+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids